# How to add a custom column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

i want to display two columns in datagrid view .
first by sql-table
second is unbounded where i want some selection button which tells which row in selected.

i get   the first column from table but i am not able to figure it out how to add second column.Following is my code.

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication14
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = @"server=.\SQLSER;database=test1;integrated security=true;";
            string sql = @"select rel.depar from rel RIGHT OUTER JOIN cust on cust.id=rel.id";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
            SqlDataReader red = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "department";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "unboundcolumn";

            while (red.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(red["depar"]);                            
            }

            red.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not assigning the grid the **DataSource** ?

Comment: I having a project in which by using limited programmic resouce i have to get maximum output :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("myColumn", "My Column");
```

Update after comment:

You can add the text in the button as a second parameter to add:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(red["depar"], "Button Text");
```

Comment: -Thanks,I want to add button in second column ,But in while loop how to put button(unbounded)+text(bounded)

Comment: -Thanks,Now i am having two column and both are text column.I want second column "Button" .The ADD method only taking all the values as text,I want one parameter as text and one as a button :)

Comment: - I am creating both the column manually by writing.But your way is good.I tried it and worked thanks .but i yet having question in mind .We cant create and set type's of columns in programme manually.because it gives flexibility. Once again thanks for your effort :)